# Include Android app module to create another app

Tags: android

In my Android application project I have some library modules and the main app module. I'm trying to create another app module (not a library) that should include the main app module so that I can reuse some base classes and resources but I'm having issues importing this app module on the new one.
The main goal is to create another app that should re-use some base classes and resources from the other one (main app module). What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I would not include the entire app as a module, I would isolate the classes I need to use to a module and import that module in the new app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add one of your mentioned modules into second. The reason for that is declaring your modules as applications in your two `build.gradle (module)` files. To prove that - if you change (in your nested module) `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` (for example) and remove the line with `applicationId` then your project should be build with success.

I see two options to resolve this problem:

1. You can move your reusable classes and resources to another module and then reuse them in your app module.
2. You can create a new flavor.