# Why is it that android does not allow calling an app module from another app module?

Tags: android, build, module, build.gradle

I see that from ([Include Android app module to create another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712860/include-android-app-module-to-create-another-app)) that we cannot call an app module from another. But what is the technical reason behind this? What DEX or app-build problems does this cause that this is disallowed in android?